# What is Lex Luthor referencing in the Batman vs Superman: Dawn of Justice trailer?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the latest *Batman vs Superman: Dawn of Justice* trailer, Lex Luthor is seen to say;

> The red capes are coming... The red capes are coming!

in a mocking tone.

We all know that Superman wears a red cape, but;

Is this a reference to something (either historical or in pop culture) that I don't get, or is it something that will be expained in the film?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a reference to the American Revolutionary figure [Paul Revere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Revere), who made a famous ride from Boston to Lexington warning everyone along the way of British troops ("redcoats") approaching by sea, and the widely-repeated story is that he shouted "The redcoats are coming! The redcoats are coming!" as he went (according to [this article](http://www.paulreverehouse.org/ride/real.html) the actual quote may have been "The regulars are coming out!")

Comment: Oh, that actually pretty cool, especially considering that Henry Cavill (who is playing Superman) is British.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Beat me to it.  Nice work! :-)

Comment: @DrRDizzle - Your profile says you are UK-based, so there's no reason you should have known this. However, the phrase (and thus the reference) would be instantly recognizable to anyone who went to a US grade school.

Answer (score -1):

In the trailer for Batman vs. Superman, it shows soldiers wearing the superman insignia on their uniforms. In one scene, they all kneel in front of superman.

In the comics from the sixties, superman used lookalike robots to help him take care of some problems when he was involved with more pressing matters.

Since the "soldiers" in the trailer never seem to show their faces, perhaps these "red capes" are superman's robot police force that he uses to help him take care of problems that do not necessarily require a super presence. After all, even a superman can't be everywhere at once.

Answer (score -3):

The Spartans wear cape.. red capes.. symbolizing their strength, honor, braveness/boldness